# How to export env variable from npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, env

I know we can declare env variables to be used inside the script run by `npm run` command like so:
`TEMP_VARIABLE=value node app.js`

But if I need to use the declared variable across multiple `npm run` scripts, then it will lead to duplicate the effort to specifying the value of variable each time, like in following code example:

```
"start": "SRC_DIR=src node src/app.js",
"lint": "SRC_DIR=src jshint src/*.js",
"coverage": "SRC_DIR=src istanbul cover --dir outputDir -i src/*.js"
```

Is there a way so that we can use `npm run-script` to export a env variable to allow something like below:

```
"scripts": {
     "set-env": "export SRC_DIR=src",    # should export the env var to be used later
     "start": "node ${SRC_DIR}/app.js",                      # use the env var set earlier.
     "lint": "jshint ${SRC_DIR}/*.js"                          # use the same env var again
     "coverage": "istanbul cover -d ./lcov -i ${SRC_DIR}/*.js"      # use again
}
```

Then we can just do:

```
npm run set-env
npm run lint
npm run start
```

Comment: Why not use `config`object: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#config?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, except that I don't want to set a static value, I want to update the value of the `$PATH` environment variable. In that case, `config` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

if you use yarn as your package manager, try this command
it is easy to find out how to make it happen

`yarn run env`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that behavior by using a different package.json feature, `npm-config`.

**Example**

This following is an adaption of your code.

```
{
    "config": {
         "srcDir": "src"
    },
    "scripts": {
         "start": "node ${npm_package_config_srcDir}/app.js",
         "lint": "jshint ${npm_package_config_srcDir}/*.js",
         "coverage": "istanbul cover -d ./lcov -i ${npm_package_config_srcDir}/*.js"
    }
}
```

**Official Documentation**

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#config
- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#special-packagejson-config-object